# Problems with Internal path length function

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I've been asked to compute the average depth of a node in both a binary search tree, and an AVL tree. Through some research, I found that the average depth of a tree is the internal path length divided by the number of nodes in a tree, and that the internal path length (the sum of the path lengths of every node in the tree) is given by this recurrence:

```
D(1) = 0, D(N) = D(i) + D(N − i − 1) + N − 1
```

where D(N) is a tree with N nodes, D(i), is the IPL of the left subtree, and D(N-i-1) is the IPL of the right subtree.

Using that, I wrote this function:

```
int internalPathLength(Node *t, int& sum) const{
        if(t == nullptr || (t->left == nullptr && t->right == nullptr)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            int a = 0;
            sum += internalPathLength(t->left, sum) + internalPathLength(t->right, sum) + (countNodes(t,a)-1);
            cout << sum << endl;
            return sum;
        }
```

This function gives me, with a binary search tree of 565 nodes, an IPL of 1,264,875,230 and an average depth of 2,238,717, a preposterously high number. Using it on an AVL tree of similar size gives me an IPL of -1,054,188,525 and an average depth of -1,865,820, which is a negative number on top of being preposterously high. Is there something wrong my interpretation/implementation of the recurrence? what else can I try? Or are the values I'm getting in the normal range for this computation after all?

Comment: I cant say what function is doing, but don't use reference. Just use pass by value i.e int sum. And also try to do it with 1 node, then 2 node and then 5 nodes...and so on,  so that you can reason your answer. And then try 565 nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass `sum` by reference, so it gets incremented way too many times. You don't really need this sum at all. This should work:

```
int internalPathLength(Node *t) const{
        if(t == nullptr || (t->left == nullptr && t->right == nullptr)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return internalPathLength(t->left) + internalPathLength(t->right) + countNodes(t) - 1;
        }
    }
```

This is not optimal, because your count function is probably also recursive.
You can count the nodes in each subtree in the same recursion and then use it. Like this:

```
int internalPathLength(Node *t, int &count) const{
        if(t == nullptr) {
            count = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else if(t->left == nullptr && t->right == nullptr){
            count = 1;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
            int leftCount;
            int rightCount;
            int sum = internalPathLength(t->left, leftCount) + internalPathLength(t->right, rightCount);

            count += leftCount + rightCount;

            return sum + count - 1;
        }
    }
```